# MYSQL Select rows from table with staggered ID

Tags: mysql

My table is like this:

```
field
-----
a
b
c
d
e
f
...
```

What I'd like to get is a query from the same table that shows me this result:

```
field fieldnew
--------------
a     b
b     c
c     d
d     e
e     f
f     ...
```

Can you get me a tip about? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use the [LAG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) window function.

```sql
SELECT field, LAG(field, 1) OVER (ORDER BY field) as fieldnew
FROM tablename;
```

For MySQL 5.7, you can use a variable that you update with each row:

```sql
SET @lag_field='';
SELECT @lag_field as fieldnew, @lag_field:=field as field
FROM tablename;
```

Note that the order of the columns is important: `fieldnew` must be first, as the variable that holds the previous row's value gets updated by the second column.

If you don't want the first row where `fieldnew` is empty, you can add `HAVING fieldnew <> ''` to the end of the query. Also, if your data are numeric, you'll need to initialize the `@lag_field` to a number, such as -1.

Comment: Hi, with MySQL 8.0 it's ok. About MySQL 5.7.x how can I get the same result? Thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a solution for MySQL 5.7. In the future, you should specify which version your question is specifically about, otherwise people will generally assume you are using the latest version.